# Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.ghjqqbt.mongodb.net at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:251:17)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js13

```
Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.ghjqqbt.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:251:17)
    at QueryReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.ghjqqbt.mongodb.net'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpqpo.png)
```

error connecting to mongo atlas through nextjs and mongoose

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96uZq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iawsg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following mongodb community forum post : https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/cant-connect-to-mongodb-atlas-querysrv-enotfound/127988/18

You can try using Google's DNS to see if that helps or even try [the standard connection string format](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#std-label-connections-standard-connection-string-format) if available. However, it might be better trying to resolve the DNS issues if that is the cause of the connection failing.